# I need to make a Excel formula to give a total characters of 26 leading with 0's

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This would be from a bulk list of names of varied length.  example: brownt = 00000000000000000000brownt

Everything I have tried puts the 0's after the name...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this given that "brown" is written in cell A1:

```
=REPT("0",26-LEN(A1))&A1
```

Comment: For simplicity this works a treat.  Massive help thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming name is in A3 use the below formula anywhere

`=CONCATENATE(REPT(0,26-LEN(A3)),A3)`